# How can I use CSS to highlight alternating groups of 10 rows in my table?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Data in my website is logically grouped in batches of 10 rows so I'd like to highlight alternating batches of 10 rows by setting a background color on the them.

Normally, such highlighting is done to alternate every other row like this:

```
table tr:nth-child(2n+2) { background: #c0c0c0; }
```

How can I use nth-child to highlight alternating groups of 10 rows?

The best I've managed to do is to highlight every 10th row in this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ppa910o8/

Comment: If it is logically grouped, it should be grouped in the markup

Comment: Yes but its not clear at a glance where 1 group of 10 ends and the next begins. changing the background color for each alternating group will make it much easier to identify each respective group

Comment: If the table is generated programatically, it would be easy to apply different classes to each table row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:nth-child()` with the format `:nth-child(n+10)` where you list the groups of 10. For example, `:nth-child(n+10)`, `:nth-child(n+20)`, `:nth-child(n+30)`... The order of the rules will matter with this method.

```css
table tr {
  background: red;
}
table tr:nth-child(n+10) {
  background: blue;
}
table tr:nth-child(n+20) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hmmm this has become quite significantly more complicated now than I'd anticipated since I never know how many groups will be in the table because the data is always being added to

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, using nth-child:

```
table tr:nth-child(20n-10),
table tr:nth-child(20n-11),
table tr:nth-child(20n-12),
table tr:nth-child(20n-13),
table tr:nth-child(20n-14),
table tr:nth-child(20n-15),
table tr:nth-child(20n-16),
table tr:nth-child(20n-17),
table tr:nth-child(20n-18),
table tr:nth-child(20n-19){
  background: #c0c0c0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but it should do the trick:

```
table tr:nth-child(n+10) {
  background: #c0c0c0;
}
table tr:nth-child(n+20) {
  background: #fff;
}
table tr:nth-child(n+30) {
  background: #c0c0c0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general principle is to double the grouping size for the `#n` part and then target `n` items using the following:

```
table tr:nth-child(20n+1),
table tr:nth-child(20n+2),
table tr:nth-child(20n+3),
table tr:nth-child(20n+4),
table tr:nth-child(20n+5),
table tr:nth-child(20n+6),
table tr:nth-child(20n+7),
table tr:nth-child(20n+8),
table tr:nth-child(20n+9),
table tr:nth-child(20n+10) {
  background: #c0c0c0;
}
```